# Setting up remote access through Landscape

Tags: remote-access, landscape

I have read about using Landscape like a VNC program and I want to access my home computer through the university PC, which runs Ubuntu 12.04. I have read that I need to add my home PC as remote desktop in Landscape website.

Although I am asked for a Server URL, which I don't know exactly what is. My home computer is connected in the web router through wireless and I use dynamic IP, and I think I should set up a static IP for that, and I don't know how to do it, already tried through `ifup` command, editing `interfaces` file, although I didn't managed to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage that computer via Landscape. To try it out, go to https://landscape.canonical.com and request a free trial. There is no need for a fixed IP.